# C prototype of a function with define name_fn in a body

Tags: c, macros, function-prototypes

Could you help me understand what the following piece of code means? Specifically, I do not understand what the effect of `name_fn` is.

```
    #define name_fn
    void name_fn Function(void);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `name_fn` expands to nothing during pre-processing. So the next line is same as

```
void Function(void);
```

Empty `#define` is useful for compatibility, self documentation and/or mechanical checking.

For example, in socket programming, you may encounter :

```
SOCKET WSAAPI
accept (IN SOCKET s,OUT struct sockaddr FAR* addr, OUT int FAR* addrlen );
```

Here `IN` and `OUT` are empty macros. They

1. Can be used to mechanically [[ check ]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383701(v=vs.85).aspx) the code.
2. Serve as a strong reminder on how the author intended use the parameters associated with them.